# Geas beyond the Grave

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, undead, content-identification

I vaguely recall the following being possible. A geas or geas variant spell with the effect that if the subject of the spell dies with the objective unresolved, the spell would turn the subject into some form of undead, still compelled to complete the task.

Where can I find this spell or how was this effect constructed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Oath of Blood**, from **Heroes of Horror**

Apparently, the effect I was remembering was from a spell that can only target a creature who has been recently put under a Geas or similar spell, rather than being a variant of Geas in and of itself.

Comment: I must have searched for “geas” only in the _names_ of spells—egg on my face there. Great find, +1.

Answer (score 7):

<s>I cannot find an official spell that works as you describe.</s> But [you did](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/192952/4563), so I just missed something.

However, worth pointing out the related *familial geas* from *Heroes of Horror*. Like the spell you describe, *familial geas* works like *geas* until the target dies. Rather than raising the target as undead to complete the task, however, the spell finds the target’s closest living adult relative and forces them to do it. This continues until the task is complete, the spell is broken, or a relative succeeds on their one save when the spell first finds them. It’s an 8th-level spell on the cleric and sor/wiz lists, and a 6th-level spell on the bard list.

Comment: Combining the two would make a rather interesting effect.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find or think of a Geas-like spell that causes a creature to return from death due to an unresolved objective but the concept rang a bell.  It reminds me one of the available prestige classes in *The Book of Exalted Deeds*: the **Risen Martyr**.

> "a risen martyr is an exalted character who continues in his earthly
> existence after his martyrdom [...] in order to finish some
> unfulfilled task." (BoED, p.68)

The description also refers to a martyred character having an exalted goal, who died for the sake of the goal, may have enough holy purpose to return as a risen martyr.

This has a similar flavour to what you describe though the creature is not "compelled". Rather, it returns to continue or fulfil that goal.

As a DM, I might allow a character or NPC, who has been under the effect of a geas spell for a long time, to return as a risen martyr, if the Geas spell had a noble cause (such as one described in the BoED like defending a city from a plague of ghosts) and if the character/NPC in question was not of an evil alignment.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a spell, but Athasian dwarves who die without completing their focus often return as (Athasian) revenants dedicated to completing their focus. In regular 2E-3.5E, revenants aren't created this way (they arise for unclear reasons to revenge their deaths on their killers), but Athas was weird, and the dwarven focus behaved very much like a self-imposed geas, where failure to complete it led to rising as a revenant.